# how to get the month and year value for the give financial year

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

how to get the month and year value for the give financial year

if my input is 2013.
my expected out put is

```
Month  Year 
4       2013
5       2013
6       2013
7       2013
8       2013
9       2013
10      2013
11      2013
12      2013
1       2014
2       2014
3       2014
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?  You will always get downvoted if you don't show some effort to solve it for yourself.

Comment: Which database system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Recursive CTE` to get the expected result.

```
DECLARE @nYearInput AS CHAR(4)
DECLARE @start DATETIME, @end DATETIME

SET @nYearInput = '2013'  -- Change your input here

SET @start = CAST(@nYearInput AS VARCHAR) + '0401'
SET @end= CAST(@nYearInput + 1 AS VARCHAR) + '0301'

;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT dt = DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(@start) - 1), @start)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, dt)
    FROM cte
    WHERE dt < DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(@end) - 1), @end)
)
SELECT YEAR(dt) AS Year, month(dt) AS month
FROM cte
```